# Why isn't my dynamically allocated array holding the correct values?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dynamic

We are covering the topic of classes at my school. I am supposed create a class called Student that we can use to hold different test scores in a dynamically allocated array. I'm struggling to figure out why when I print out the array of a specific instance of this class, it gives me completely incorrect values. I know my setter function for the class is setting the correct values but whenever I go to print them out they are completely wrong. Below is my code. The commented out portion in main() was just being used to test my logic for the makeArray() function.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Student {

private:

    string name;
    int id;
    int* testptr;
    int num;

    void makeArray() {
        int array[num];
        testptr = &array[num];

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            array[i] = 0;
        }
    }

public:

    Student() {
        setName("None");
        setID(10);
        num = 3;
        makeArray();
    }

    Student(int n) {
        setName("None");
        setID(10);
        if (n > 0)
            num = n;
        else
            num = 3;
        makeArray();
    }

    Student(string nm, int i, int n) {
        setName(nm);
        setID(i);
        if (n > 0)
            num = n;
        else
            num = 3;
        makeArray();
    }

    void setName(string nm) {
        name = nm;
    }

    void setID(int i) {
        if (i >= 10 && i <= 99){
            id = i;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Error: Cannot set id to " << i << " for " << getName();
            id = 10;
        }
    }

    void setScore(int i, int s) {
        if ((i >= 0 && i <= num) && (s >= 0 && s <= 100)) {
            //Here is where I set the values for the array. They come out correct in the console.
            testptr[i] = s;
            cout << testptr[i] << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "The test " << i << " cannot be set to " << s << " for " << getName() << endl;
        }
    }

    string getName() const {
        return name;
    }

    int getID() const {
        return id;
    }

    void showScore() {
        //This is where I print out the values of the array. They come out incorrect here.
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            cout << "Test " << i << " had a score of " << testptr[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    void display() {
        cout << "Calling the display function" << endl;
        cout << "The Name: " << getName() << endl;
        cout << "The ID: " << getID() << endl;
        showScore();
    }

    ~Student() {

    }

};

int main() {
    Student c("Joe", 40, 5);

    c.setScore(0, 90);
    c.setScore(1, 91);
    c.setScore(2, 92);
    c.setScore(3, 93);
    c.setScore(4, 94);


    c.display();

    /**int* testpointer;
    int num = 3;
    int array[num];
    testpointer = &array[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        testpointer[i] = i;
        cout << testpointer[i] << endl;
    }**/


}
```

Comment: You are not allocating your array dynamically.  It's falling out of scope and causing the dreaded UB.

Comment: Use some standard [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), probably a `std::vector`

Answer (score 1):

The problem (actually the set of problems) is in this function

> ```
> void makeArray() {
>     int array[num];
>     testptr = &array[num];
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
>         array[i] = 0;
>     }
> }
> ```

The first statement `int array[num]`, since `num` is not a compile-time constant, is not valid C++.     If your compiler supports it, it is a compiler specific extension.  (Technically, this is a variable length array, which is a feature in C from the 1999 C standard, optional in C from 2011, but has never been a part of C++ in any standard or draft.).

Second, if your compiler does support that construct, it creates an array of automatic storage duration, which ceases to exist when the function returns.   This means `testptr` then contains a dangling pointer.   After the function returns, any dereferencing of `testptr` (e.g. accessing array elements) will give undefined behaviour.

If you really must use dynamic memory allocation, use a "new expression", such as `testptr = new int[num]`.  Just remember it will then be necessary to do `delete [] testptr` in the your class destructor.   Also look up "rule of three", since you will need to write copy constructor and assignment operator to properly manage the array when creating other instances of your class.

Better yet, `#include <vector>`, and change `testptr` to be of type `std::vector<int>`.   Read the documentation for the standard vector class for how to use it, including managing its size.

Also, `#include <string>` as well.   Without it, your code is not required to compile with your usage the `std::string` type - you just got lucky, with your implementation, that `<iostream>` includes `<string>`.   That is not required by the C++ standard and, in practice, happens with some compilers and not others.

There are other problems in your code as well, but the above should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple concerns in your code, but let's start with the question first.
The problem is that in current implementation you are not using a dynamic array but just the pointer to some random data in memory. Dynamically allocated objects are created using `new` operator. In your case you allocate object on a stack:

```
void makeArray() {
    int array[num];         // creates local object on stack
    testptr = &array[num];  // stores pointer to local object

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
} // stack is being destroyed here along with array object
  // testptr points to memory that should no be addressed anymore
```

It is a pretty common mistake in C++ to return/store pointer or reference to a local object outside of the scope where the object was declared. The correct way to initialize the pointer would be:

```
void makeArray() {
    // note parenthesis at the end,
    // default zero-initializer will be called 
    testptr = new int[num]();
}
```

Note, in that case, you have to remember to free allocated memory when it's not more required using. The best way to achieve that is to put delete call into destructor:

```
   ~Student() {
       delete[] array;
   }
```

Then the memory will be released when Student object will go out of scope.

But I strictly encourage you to familiarize yourself with the concept of "smart pointers" which are specially designed to reduce manual memory management work. In modern C++ "raw" pointers are considered very bad practice due to many mistakes it could lead.
Even better approach would be not using pointers at all but rather one standard C++  containers, like `std::vector<int>`

Answer (score 1):

In order for the functions in a class to share data you declare variables at class scope.

```
class Foo
{
public:
  MyFunc1() { _n = 1; }
  MyFunc2() { _n = 2; }
private:
  int32_t n; // can be used by all member functions
};
```

In your case you declared an array at function scope which is destroyed once you leave the function.

In addition you cannot declare an array with a variable size on the stack, instead you need to allocate the array on the heap

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo():_array(nullptr),_size(0) {}
  void AllocateArray(int size) { _array = new int32_t[size]; _size = size; }
  void DestroyArray() { delete [] _array; _size = 0; }
private:
  int32_t* _array;
  int8_t _size;
};
```

Normally you would instead use one of the C++ containers for this (e.g. std::vector) instead of using a raw pointer.